What was the document that Paul and Chloe signed with Sabrina?
In the 2019 French film Get In (originally titled Furie), it seems that the central reason behind Sabrina and Eric being able to squat in the house is a document that allowed Sabrina and Eric to pay the utility bills, which grants some sort of ownership in the house to them despite Paul and Chloe still being the ones paying the mortgage. I'm not familiar with French real estate laws, so I'm unsure as to how much legal basis such an argument has past it driving the plot forward. I watched the film on Netflix, so I don't know if there's some commentary from the director that better explains why this document is the crux of the disagreement.

There's a legal disposition in French law called "convention d'occupation précaire"1 (roughly translated as "precarious/tenuous occupancy agreement").
It says that some people (landlords) may agree to let other people occupy their home for a short period of time under that "precarious occupancy agreement". This means that the 'tenants' (for lack of a better word, because legally, they're not!) will pay some bills for the time spent and take care of the house/apartment.
They will not pay rent, making this an agreement and not a lease.
Rights (and laws) differentiate between the two.

Original: Pour qu’un engagement soit qualifié de convention précaire et non de bail, le propriétaire doit justifier d’une raison qui lui avait permis de concéder à titre précaire l’occupation du logement.

Translation: For a commitment to be qualified as a precarious agreement and not a lease, the owner must provide proof of a reason which allowed him to grant precarious occupation of the accommodation.


This can be because of a trip, holidays... for weeks or months.
It's then very difficult to prove when it stops, and under which circumstances. Then, lawyers and judges step in.

1. On this page, there are many examples of what constitutes a precarious agreement and what constitutes a lease.

Ah, and from what I remember in the film, part of the issue was that they didn't specifically state a two month duration, so Eric and Sabrina are claiming that their tenancy has not ended.

I haven't seen the movie, but have a fair knowledge of this kind of situations, having been a tenant for years, and having heard of such stories every single year :)
